# Detect duplicate row within a batch - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario:
I have a transaction, in which a batch of records is being sent from one table (source) to another(target). The transaction is defined within TRY-CATCH statements to detect errors. Having a PK constraint defined on the target table, I want to detect records/rows which violate the constraint, and then isolate these records into a separate table (duplicates). The TRY will detect the violation, however which T-SQL statement(s) can identify those rows and only isolate them?

Comment: A single statement is atomic - that is, it either succeeds as a whole or does not. TSQL does not have a mechanism to know which rows violated any particular constraint - and do not assume that some subset of rows only violate just one constraint. If YOU are writing the code, then YOU know what the primary key columns are and can find duplicates by simply joining. Without that assumption, you must write code to interrogate the meta-data of the table to identify the primary key columns and dynamically generate the appropriate query.

Comment: Shorter answer - use a tool that has this feature built into it. SSIS is one example.

Comment: Would it not be easier to make sure the source table was deduped before being sent to try/catch?

Answer (score 1):

Bellow a simplified script that identify duplicates on pk-values and extract only one recordset of a PK to the target table and the other to a duplicate table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #target;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #duplicates;
 
CREATE TABLE #source ( pk INT, value INT )
 
INSERT INTO #source
VALUES (10, 100), (10, 101), (10, 102), (10, 103), (20, 200), (20, 201)
 
SELECT *
INTO   #target
FROM   ( SELECT PkRowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pk ORDER BY value), pk, value FROM #source ) AS sub
WHERE  PkRowId = 1;
 
SELECT *
INTO   #duplicates
FROM   ( SELECT PkRowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pk ORDER BY value), pk, value FROM #source ) AS sub
WHERE  PkRowId > 1;
 
SELECT * FROM #target;
SELECT * FROM #duplicates;
```

Which recordset will get PkRowId 1 you can control with ORDER BY if necessary.